# Inf and Nan in gradient descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

Why the code results in inf and nan after some iterations? I just want to implement linear regression in one variable through mathematical code.
My code for gradient descent and the output of the function is given below.

```
def grad_desc(x,y,n_iter=1000,learning_rate=0.01):
    costs=[]
    m=len(y)
    w,b=initialize()
    for i in range(n_iter):
        h=hypothesis(w,b,x)
        J=(1/(2*m))*np.sum(pow(h-y,2))
        costs.append(J)
        dw=(1/m)*np.sum((h-y)*x)
        db=(1/m)*np.sum(h-y)
        w=w-learning_rate*dw
        b=b-learning_rate*db
    return costs
```

Output:

```
[305686.32565862866,
 51793655254.27448,
 5.5831778397783917e+17,
 6.018501673635295e+24,
 6.487767976418622e+31,
 6.993623263449072e+38,
 7.538920400488151e+45,
 8.126734693007571e+52,
 8.760381229951235e+59,
 9.443433579801061e+66,
 3.6479977631586865e+193,
 3.932434407976516e+200,
 6.6513523667622165e+249,
 7.16996243001644e+256,
 7.729008841080554e+263,
 8.331644447035739e+270,
 8.981267924402674e+277,
 9.681542946615173e+284,
 1.043641884599361e+292,
 1.1250152886745234e+299,
 inf,
 inf,
 inf,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
```

Comment: Try lowering `learning rate` to `0.0001` and post the `costs` again.

Comment: Yeah, it's working but there is a reduction in cost per iteration is very low and I've to increase the number of iterations. If I increase the learning_rate a little bit then again inf

Comment: If you don't understand why this is happening and why this is expected, check out some ML tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `np.sum()` command as it just returns a scaler. You have to pass the axis in `np.sum(_, axis=_)` to have the output as a vector. By doing so you will be able to update weights non-uniformly.

Comment: I missed this, nice!